# Asp.net WCF and integrated Windows authentication and IIS 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have been struggling with this problem, read many questions, articles but could not solve it. so here I am.

Webservice is within a website and I access it from a Console application [testing]. here is my Web.Config code

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Services.CilsDataReceiveBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WindowsAuth">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Services.CilsDataReceiveBehavior" name="Services.CilsDataReceive">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="WindowsAuth" contract="Services.ICilsDataReceive" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Below is my code and app.config used in **Console** application.

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICilsDataReceive" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://wgb01wa7002.worldwide.co.uk:44001/Services/CilsDataReceive.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICilsDataReceive"
                contract="ICilsDataReceive" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICilsDataReceive" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Below is the cs code

```
icDateList.titlesField = titles.ToArray();
            var cilsDataReceiveClient = new CilsDataReceiveClient();
            try
            {
                cilsDataReceiveClient.RecieveICDateList(icDateList);
                Console.WriteLine(" O_O   Service saved the data   O_O");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                cilsDataReceiveClient.Abort();
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                throw;
            }

            finally
            {
                Console.Read();

            }
```

error message is
"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'."

If a change my Console application app.config to

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
```

I get below error
"'http://wgb01wa7002.worldwide.co.uk:44001/Services/CilsDataReceive.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information."

I tried many things tries WsHttpBinding but i think that uses Https rather http.

Could you please suggest something?

Edit: if I access it from browser I get "Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service."

Edit 2: i tried with netTCPBinding and error changed "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'. It seems I should not use it.
Parameter name: via"

Edit 3: I tried with wsHttpBinding and still i am getting errors. its like never ending errors.

Comment: WsHttpBinding is not particular to SSL. It can be configured with SSL on or off. This is configurable via security mode (transport => SSL).

Comment: OK but what could be the solution to my problem? should i use netTCPBinding?

Comment: Try it, report your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, is your desktop environment set up to test ssl?  if not, add it.

second, your likely missing WsHttpsBinding

Comment: I do not want to use SSL. I want to use Basic Http binding